# Rails: nested resources issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

those are my routes:

```
  resources :forums, :shallow=>true do
    resources :topics, :shallow=>true do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
```

within `topics/show.html.erb` I added a form to leave a post (`Post` is like a comment for a `Topic`)

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "content" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the problem is that the field `:topic_id` within the model `Post` stays empty.
shouldn't it get the topic's id automatically?

thanks

Comment: Automatically? No. Show the code that saves your form data to it's new model instances.

Answer (score 1):

The topic_id is not inside params[:post] in create action of your PostsController.
So you need to assign topic_id to post in action manually, like this:

```
...
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.topic_id = params[:topic_id]
if @post.save
  flash.notice "Post created successfully"
else
  flash.error "Error saving post"
end
...
```

Comment: post = Topic.find(params[:topic_id]).posts.build(params[:post]) might be more resilient.  Putting the Topic.find in a before filter for that controller would also be a good idea.